# Context processors, caching

Tags: django, caching

I have a 'work' model that have three main categories  drawing, motion, web. I am trying to make caching inside custom context processor:

```
#custom context processor
works = cache.get(cache_key_works)
if not works:
    workList = Work.objects.filter(publish=1).order_by('-publish_from')
    works = {'drawings': [], 'webdesigns': []}
    for w in workList:
        s = w.category.get_root().slug_en
        if s == 'drawing':
            works['drawings'].append(w)
        elif s == 'web-design':
            works['webdesigns'].append(w)
return {'WORKS': works}
```

Than i use  WORKS in the templates according to category...

Is this a good or unnecessary practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works and it's not unnecessary practice, having a good cache is key however I'm a bit confused as to why you're looping over the `Work` QuerySet as you do.

Wouldn't this work for you:

```
#custom context processor
works = cache.get(cache_key_works)
if not works:
    drawings = Work.objects.filter(publish=1, category__root__slug='drawing').order_by('-publish_from')
    web_designs = Work.objects.filter(publish=1, category__root__slug='web_designs').order_by('-publish_from')
    worktypes = {'drawings': drawings, 'web_designs': web_designs}

return {'work_types': work_types}
```

NOTE: The `category__root__slug='drawing'` is just conceptually since you need to replace it with your correct model structure. Also you're never putting the `work_types` back into the cache if you get a cache miss, which is something you should look over too.

Comment: And say i want to filter drawings according to a year, is it a good practise to do it inside the template like  {% if drawing.date.year == selected_year %} (inside for loop)?

Comment: No, it's never a good idea to do template based logic. Well, not according to the pattern that Django tries to follow anyways. What I suggest you do in that case is make a helper that takes the QuerySet does additional filtering and then present it to the template.

Comment: Do you mean a custom template tag by saying helper?